# How do I get administrator access to my PC using a secondary account and Remote Desktop?

Tags: networking, windows-8, remote-desktop

### The issue

My pc's graphics card died out on me a week ago.
I need to be able to control the pc remotely.

#### Specs

- PC is connected to home network via cable to router.
- PC is running Windows 8.0

#### Current situation

I managed to connect via Remote Dekstop via a secondary account. But my main administrator account does not have a password and every time I try to log in using that account I get a message saying that the account can't be accessed because it does not have a password.

### Question

How do I get administrator access to my PC?

Comment: Unless the default Administrator account is already enabled you are better off spending the $30 to purchase a replacement graphics card.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't really care about the money, I'm sure this could be done using a faceless box.

Comment: So does that mean your default `Administrator` account is enabled?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but it does not have a password set (blank password) and so I can't use it to log in or administer the OS remotely.

Comment: You can't.  You have to be able to log into the account, to disable the security policy, that is preventing you from logging into the account without a password.  You should always have an account with a password for this reason, so the solution, just replace the graphics card ( you should do this anyways ).

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. For security reasons, unauthenticated logons are allowed only at the console.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way other than providing password for the Administrator/User account. Once you are in, you are able to [disable](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=303846) this security feature